# How can I handle in Apex if a new Apex Job is enqueued

Tags: apex, api, asyncapexjob

I would like to know if there is a way to handle the creation of a new Apex Job inserted the Flex Queue, since the object `AsyncApexJob` is not supported in Triggers. I was also considering handling an event, but the creation of a job doesn't trigger any events.

Edit: Sorry I didn't clarify. What i want to accomplish is to send a warning email to a specific address if the number of jobs enqueued are surpassing the 60% of the limit (100). I'm aware that there is an option in the user settings to accomplish this (Send Apex Warning Emails), but we don't want to cover all the limits.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, exactly? This sounds like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You might have better luck if you explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is creating a scheduler that runs every, for example, 30 seconds and makes SOQL on AsyncApexJob and then - sends email to specific user.

Here is what I mean as a sample:

```
public with sharing class jobCheckScheduler implements Schedulable {
    public static final String JOB_NAME = 'JOB_CHECK_SCHEDULER';

    public void execute(System.SchedulableContext sc) {
        // query SOQL here for checking the jobs amount and sending email

        List <CronJobDetail> croneJobList = [
                SELECT Id
                FROM CronJobDetail
                WHERE Name = :JOB_NAME
        ];

        if (!croneJobList.isEmpty()) {
            List <CronTrigger> croneTriggerList = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetailId = :croneJobList.get(0).id];
            if (!croneTriggerList.isEmpty()) System.abortJob(croneTriggerList.get(0).id);
        }

        Datetime workTime = System.now().addSeconds(30);
        String CRONEXP = '' + workTime.second() + ' ' + workTime.minute() + ' ' + workTime.hour()
                + ' ' + workTime.day() + ' ' + workTime.month() + ' ? ' + workTime.year();

        System.schedule(JOB_NAME, CRONEXP, new ExportLeadsToMassApiScheduler());
    }
}
```

Comment: @IllusiveBrian It does. I remove the job in ```System.abortJob(croneTriggerList.get(0).id);``` and only after tht schedule next run ```System.schedule(JOB_NAME, CRONEXP, new ExportLeadsToMassApiScheduler());```. It is working solution, I tested it.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that

Comment: I think that's a good way to solve this. The cons are that this won't be in real time and additionally is a bit curious that we schedule a batch to alert on batch limits..